# Dlookup date criteria wrong

Tags: ms-access, vba

I use a Dlookup with a date criteria. With some dates this works fine, with other dates it returns a #error. I can not figur out what I am doing wrong.

```
=Nz(DLookUp("[TSB]";"tblCTLATL";"[Day]=#" & Format([cboActivityDate];'Medium Date') & "#"))
```

In my opinion it has something to with the formatting. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you edit your question and give us examples of dates which work and dates which do not work?

Comment: Like dates in october and march didn't work, But september and august works fine.

Comment: He means that you edit and [to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Medium Date* is not an appropriate date format for a date literal. The appropriate formats are yyyy-mm-dd and mm/dd/yyyy.

Adjust your `Format` function:

```
=Nz(DLookUp("[TSB]";"tblCTLATL";"[Day]=#" & Format([cboActivityDate];'yyyy-mm-dd') & "#"))
```

Comment: @C.F.Aarssen can you accept this answer if it solved your problem, according to your comment?

Comment: @C.F.Aarssen You can accept the answer, see the [help section on accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) and the [help section on what to do if someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)